# Изменение данных в /proc

Tags: android, linux

Нуждаюсь в изменении файла if_inet6 в директории /proc. Знаю что это виртуальная папка отображающая настройки системы. Соответственно в чем вопрос подойдет ли данное решение [Ubuntu 18 редактировать корневые файлы](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1046737/ubuntu-18-edit-root-files).Или если есть более простое решение прошу подсказать.

Comment: что и для чего вы там собрались менять?

Comment: Меняйте настройки, файлы поменяюся)

Comment: Файлы в */proc* устанавливаются с помощью `sysctl` (не путать с `systemctl`!).